# product category image in custom WooCommerce theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for some help finding a php snippet that will display the product category image in a custom WooCommerce theme. I am using a plugin that executes the php code within a widget and it is working fine for the product category name. I just can't find anything that works for the category image. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the category ID and it's in `$cat_ID`:

```
// get the thumbnail ID
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat_ID, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
// get the image URL
$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
// print the IMG HTML
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" />';
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm pretty new to this. do you know of a way it would detect the category? I would prefer to have one sidebar for all category pages. The title populated correctly using  `<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>`

Comment: This will do it, then you can use `$term->term_id` to get the category ID: http://ericwijaya.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/display-product-category-description-in-product-page-on-woocommerce/

Answer (score 0):

To display the category image for the currently displayed category in archive-product.php, use the current category term_id when is_product_category() is true:

```
// verify that this is a product category page
    if (is_product_category()){
        global $wp_query;
        // get the query object
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        // get the thumbnail id user the term_id
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
        // get the image URL
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
        // print the IMG HTML
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" width="762" height="365" />';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code :-

```
global $product;

if (is_product_category()) {

    global $wp_query;

    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);

    $image = wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail_id);

    if ($image) {

        echo '<img src="' . esc_url($image) . '" alt="" />';

    }    }
```